# Image does not load in Phonegap app from Amazon S3

Tags: jquery-mobile, amazon-s3, cordova

Using Phonegap 2.5 and jQuery mobile 1.3 we are building an app. We have problem at showing images from Amazon S3 server. We have allowed all URLs (for Android   tag).

We are using  and all images are showing but these from S3. For example  http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/astfbackup/currentimages/shop/images/stories/boardwalk-empire_speech.png this is one of the images which is not shown in PhoneGap app, but is shown everywhere else (even in Ripple emulator).

Does anyone have a clue what could be a problem?